# How do I solve this iteration with check in Golang?

Tags: go, concurrency

I have some Golang codes which look like the following

```
package main

type MyStruct struct {
    field1 string
    field2 float64
    field3 int
    field4 bool
}

func main() {
    names := getNames()
    myStruct := getMyStruct(names)
    writeToCsv(myStruct)
}

func getNames() []string {
    // get list of names then return
}

func getMyStruct(names []string) []Mystruct {
    myStruct := []MyStruct{}
    for i := range names {
        // do something then assign the computed values
        myStruct = append(myStruct, MyStruct{
            field1: value1,
            field2: value2,
            field3: value3,
            field4: value4,
        })
    }
    return myStruct
}

func writeToCsv(myStruct []MyStruct) {
    // prepare writer then write header
    for i := range myStruct {
        // create the slice of string to be written to csv
    }
}
```

It works correctly. However, I would like to be able to limit the number of rows written in a single csv file to e.g. 500,000 rows without having rows of the same `name` (from the `names` slice) being separated.

For example, `name1` has 200,000 MyStruct rows, `name2` has 289,000 MyStruct rows and `name3` has 180,000 MyStruct rows. Since the total number of rows from `name1` to `name3` is already more than 500,000, I would like it to be written in a single csv file. After that, I would like to continue getting the MyStruct data for `name4`, `name5` and so on and so forth until their total again exceed 500,000.

Also, since I'm using Golang, I think it would be better if I also know how to do the following concurrently:

```
1. Get the MyStruct rows
2. Write them to CSV
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit1: If someone can show me how to use closures for the problem above (which I think might be a possible solution), I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your structs are generated in order, the trick is to have a counter for rows and remember the previous value.

```
func generate(structs []MyStruct) {
    var count = 0
    var previous = structs[0].name

    for _, s := range structs {
        if s.name != previous && count > 500000 {
            // flush your csv here
            count = 0
        }

        // append to your buffer here

        previous = s.name
    }
}
```

For concurrently doing it, you want to look at channels and goroutines.

For example

```
func makeStructs(names []string) chan MyStruct {
    var c = make(chan MyStruct)
    go func() {
        for _, n := range names {
            // do you thing
            c <- struct{...}
        }
        close(c)
    }()
}

func generate(structs chan MyStruct) {
    var count = 0
    var previous = ""

    for s := range structs {
        if s.name != previous && count > 500000 {
            // flush your csv here
            count = 0
        }

        // append to your buffer here

        previous = s.name
    }
}
```